# How to change WIFI credentials at runtime in ESP32?

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp32

I'm a little bit new to **ESP32** and **Arduino ID**. I've been working on a project in which I want to switch the wifi network from one to another at any given time. But whenever I'm trying to close the existing connection (network) and reconnect to the new one, ESP32 **crashes** and gets **rebooted**. A bit peculiar behaviour I would say. Additionally, I even tried to use the **EEPROM** for the storage purpose, so, even when my ESP32 gets rebooted, it will take the updated values from the storage. Unfortunately, sometimes ESP32 crashes even when I update the variable which was being passed earlier to **WiFi.begin()**. Lastly, In my application, I'll be providing the new SSID and Password through the serial (COM) port. Can anyone help in achieving this task?

Comment: Please share a minimal, viable example of the code that demonstrates this problem instead of describing it. Also please share the messages that are output at the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar task with persisting values in memory. The ESP32 lacks an eeprom so you need to use some nvs (non volatile storage) functions as they are called for ESP32. See https://github.com/rpolitex/ArduinoNvs for example.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Adding links is good, but better showing how they solve the question.